# Why laravel eloquent insert function missing values after 50k entries while using chunks?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an excel sheet that has more than 1 million rows in it. I want to insert and update these rows of data to a table. I have used "Maatwebsite" excel library and imported excel to a temporary table. After this, I want to insert temporary table data into the actual table.

Following is the code for fetching data from the temp table.

```
$temp_products = ProductTemp::limit(100000)->get()->map(function(ProductTemp $temp_product) {
        return [
            'msrp' => $temp_product->msrp,
            'price' => $temp_product->unit_price,
            'product_overview' => $temp_product->part_description,
            'manufacturer_id' => $temp_product->manufacturer_id,
            'upc' => $temp_product->upc,
            'manufacturer_part_number' => $temp_product->part_no
        ];
    });
```

Then I tried both the `chunk()` and `array_chunk()` functions to divide data into parts.

```
//$chunks = $temp_products->chunk(5000);
$arr_chunks = array_chunk($temp_products->toArray(), 5000);
```

Then I loop through them to insert rows in a actual table like this with the `array_chunk()` function.

```
foreach($arr_chunks as $chunk)
    {          
        Product::insert($chunk);
    }
```

and with `chunk()` function like this.

```
foreach($arr_chunks as $chunk)
        {
            Product::insert($chunk->toArray());           
        }
```

I have also tried the `sleep()` function with this but not helping. After 50, 000 entries it's missing values or adding more. Also, I tried chunks of 100, and 1000 but the result is the same and the page never finishes loading.

Here is the full function code, this might help with what I have tried more and what I am missing.

```
public function insertFromTempTable()
    {
        // dd("HERE 1111111 22222222222 4444444444");
        $temp_products = ProductTemp::all()->map(function (ProductTemp $temp_product) {
            return [
                'msrp' => $temp_product->msrp,
                'price' => $temp_product->unit_price,
                'product_overview' => $temp_product->part_description,
                'manufacturer_id' => $temp_product->manufacturer_id,
                'upc' => $temp_product->upc,
                'manufacturer_part_number' => $temp_product->part_no,
            ];
        });
        // dd($temp_products);
        $inc = 0;
        dump("Started on: " . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        // sleep(10);
        // foreach ($temp_products as $value) {
        //     Product::insert($temp_products[$inc]);
        //     $inc++;
        // }
        // dd($temp_products->toArray());
        // Product::insert($temp_products->toArray());
        // $chunks = $temp_products->chunk(100);
        $chunk_sub = 5000;
        $arr_chunks = array_chunk($temp_products->toArray(), $chunk_sub);
        // dd($arr_chunks[0]);
        // dd(gettype($chunks[0]->toArray()));
        // dd($chunks[0]->toArray());
        $chunk_temp = 0;
        foreach ($arr_chunks as $chunk) {
            // dd($chunk->toArray());
            // dump(count($chunk->toArray()));
            // Product::insert($chunk->toArray());
            $chunk_temp = $chunk_temp + $chunk_sub;
            
            Product::insert($chunk);
            
        }

        // $temp_products->chunk(2, function ($subset) {
        //     dd("HHHHHHH");
        //     $subset->each(function ($item) {
        //         dd($item);
        //     });
        // });

        dump("Ended on: " . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    }
```

After inserting I want to compare an excel sheet on daily basis, that might have more than 1 million rows. That will check for MSRP and price columns and update them. Please let me know which will be the best solution for all of this.

**UPDATE 01:**

I have tried using a raw query. There were 104, 8575 rows in the temp table but after the query run, there are 103, 9229 rows in the products table. Following is the code for the raw query.

```
$results = DB::table('products')->insertUsing(
        ['msrp', 'price', 'product_overview', 'manufacturer_id', 'upc', 'manufacturer_part_number',],
        function ($query) {
            $query
                ->select(['msrp', 'unit_price', 'part_description', 'manufacturer_id', 'upc', 'part_no',])
                ->from('products_temp');
        }
    );
```

When I dump and die the `$results` variable it output 104, 8575.

Comment: An insert ... select ... would be a lot easier to copy stuff over between two tables.

Comment: At one point, when `$chunk_temp` hits 50000, you're going to skip that insert and sleep instead, so you'll be missing 5k records

Comment: I just tried that too and not helping. I wanted to sleep after 50k entries then continue.

Comment: Is `ProductTemp` grabbing data from a table in your database? If so, I agree with Shadow. Using `INSERT INTO products (columns) SELECT (columns) FROM product_temp` (or whatever everything is named) will be a lot easier and faster

Comment: you are correct @aynber, but that is not the main concern. It still missing value after 50k.

Comment: if `INSERT ... SELECT` is missing data, then your table is missing data. You'll need to look at your initial insert process instead.

Comment: @aynber So I should use the raw query instead of eloquent.

Comment: And what about in case of comparing and updating?

Comment: Raw is easier to move it from one table to another. Comparing is a whole other ball of wax, and probably a whole other question. You can use updating in the raw query as long as there is a unique key

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lac* that are not understood globally

Comment: I have tried the raw query but it still missing some values. Please have a look at the updated post. @aynber

Comment: Ok, ⅜Do you want to compare an excel sheet daily? Does that temp table contain *all* the records? Laravel has something called `upsert` , it takes away this insert problem. Last time I used `upsert` I so counted the collection, right before I started to upset the data. Having it in a collection makes comparing easier. `upsert` is a good replacement for `insertOrUpdate`

Comment: Yes, I have to upload daily and compare excel sheets with table rows. I have tried `upsert` but it was too slow. @UnderDog